# Rails+AngularJS returning weird error on $resource call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm working on integrating AngularJS with Rails and I'm getting some errors that's driving me nuts.  I have a AngularJS factory and a controller that's making a call to the index method of a Rails controller, however, I'm getting this error back in the JavaScript console.

```
Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an array but got an object
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.22/$resource/badcfg?p0=array&p1=object
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:79:12
    at $http.then.value.$resolved (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular-resource.js?body=1:541:23)
    at wrappedCallback (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:11547:81)
    at wrappedCallback (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:11547:81)
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:11633:26
    at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:12659:28)
    at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:12471:31)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:12763:24)
    at done (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:8358:45)
    at completeRequest (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:8572:7)
```

My code is like this:

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require angular
//= require angular-resource
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery.raty
//= require welcome
//= require users
//= require angular/config
//= require angular/factories
//= require_tree ./angular/controllers
```

config.js

```
var app = angular.module('sideSkillz', ['ngResource'])
```

factories.js

```
var app = window.app;

app.factory('Skillzer', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('/skillzers/:id',
    { id: "@id" },
    { update: { method: 'PUT' } }
  );
});
```

skillzersCtrl.js

```
function skillzersCtrl ($scope, Skillzer) {
  $scope.skillzers = Skillzer.query();
}
```

skillzers_controller.rb

```
class SkillzersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json

  before_action :find_skillzer, only: :show

  def index
    @skillzers = Skillzer.all
    respond_with @skillzers
  end

  def show
    respond_with @skillzer
  end

  private

  def find_skillzer
    @skillzer = Skillzer.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

skillzers/index.html.haml

```
.container{ ng: { controller: 'skillzersCtrl' } }
  %p{ ng: { repeat: 'skillzer in skillzers' } }
    {{skillzer[0].first_name}}
```

This post has been quite long already with all the code, but this is driving me nuts right now.  Also, I understand that it isn't the most efficient code, since it loads the html, and angularjs needs to make another api call, but I'm really using this as a learning exercise for angularjs.  Can anyone pinpoint what I'm doing wrong?  The examples seem pretty similar to many sample apps (especially Railscasts AngularJS one), but it doesn't work!

Thank you!

Comment: the issue is that `Skillzer.query()` gets an object (like a hash) from database, but it expects an array. Check your json response

Answer (score 0):

Your factory configure for single record. That's why you are getting this error. Below factory for index action.

factories.js

```
var app = angular.module('sideSkillz');

app.factory('Skillzer', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('/skillzers',
    { }, // Query parameters
    { 'query': { method: 'GET' } }
  );
});
```

Comment: If that's the case, then how come many examples online, for example, https://github.com/railscasts/405-angularjs, does not do that?  In fact, it seems that $resource comes with the query method that should map to the index method of the appropriate controller.